# Crosstab query with CTE returns error: relation "cte" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, crosstab

I have two schemas on my PostgreSQL server, and I'm trying to create a pivoted table:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT l.fcid, t.fixture_code, COUNT(f.fixture_type_id) AS count  
        FROM aim.locations as l
            JOIN aim.fixture_instances as f
            ON l.id = f.location_id
            JOIN aim.fixture_types as t
            ON f.fixture_type_id = t.id
   GROUP BY l.fcid, t.fixture_code
   )
SELECT *
FROM lab.CROSSTAB('SELECT fcid, fixture_code, SUM(count) FROM cte group by 1,2 order by 1,2', 
                   'Select DISTINCT fixture_code from cte order by 1') 
                AS CT (FCID integer, "fx1" bigint, "fx2" bigint)
ORDER BY fcid;
```

However, I receive an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist
> LINE 1: Select DISTINCT fixture_code from cte order by 1
> ```

The query worked when I had only one schema.
I use a CTE so I could create a view with the query.
What's wrong here?

Comment: Put the CTE definition before the queries you pass to the function, if you want to access it in these queries.

Comment: @stickybit not sure what you mean. Isn't it already like you described. Will it be possible to show? thank you!

Comment: No it isn't as I described. Put the CTE **in** the arguments of `crosstab()` **not** the query selecting **from** `crosstab()` -- `... crosstab('WITH ... SELECT ...', 'WITH ... SELECT ...', ...`

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you a lot! @sticky bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't need the outer `SELECT` of the query string argument at all. The added `sum(count)` changes nothing in this constellation. The query in the CTE already delivers the end result to be fed to `crosstab()`. Get rid of the CTE altogether - thereby also fixing the immediate cause of the error:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   lab.crosstab(
         $$
         SELECT l.fcid, t.fixture_code, count(*) AS cnt
         FROM   aim.locations         l
         JOIN   aim.fixture_instances f ON l.id = f.location_id
         JOIN   aim.fixture_types     t ON f.fixture_type_id = t.id
         GROUP  BY 1,2
         ORDER  BY 1,2
         $$
      ,  $$VALUES ('fx1'), ('fx2')$$
       ) AS ct(fcid int, fx1 bigint, fx2 bigint);
```

Some other things:

There is no point in running `SELECT DISTINCT` when you have to spell out corresponding columns names in the column definition list anyway. Replaced it with a plain `VALUES` expression.

`f.fixture_type_id` is `NOT NULL` by definition of the query, so use the faster equivalent `count(*)`.

Basics here:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)